# How do I automatically open an element on selection of another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using https://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/ date and time picker but I would like some help with the current flow. So right now, the date and time picker is in the different input fields. To pick a date I need to click on Date input and to pick a time I need to click on time input.

What I basically want is one input for both picking. So when I click on the "only" one input it should load date picker by default and soon as I choose the date it should automatically open the time picker, and then I'll choose the time too. To display in the input field it should be something like, "29 Apr, 2019 at 14:00"

Can someone help me to achieve this?

```js
// DatePicker
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
  format: 'dd mmm, yyyy',
  today: '',
  clear: '',
  close: '',
});

// TimePicker
$('.timepicker').pickatime({
  clear: '',
  format: 'HH:i'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://hateable-tests.000webhostapp.com/classic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://hateable-tests.000webhostapp.com/classic.date.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://hateable-tests.000webhostapp.com/classic.time.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://hateable-tests.000webhostapp.com/picker.js"></script>
<script src="https://hateable-tests.000webhostapp.com/legacy.js"></script>
<script src="https://hateable-tests.000webhostapp.com/picker.date.js"></script>
<script src="https://hateable-tests.000webhostapp.com/picker.time.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="datepicker">
<input type="text" class="timepicker">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

- hide the timepicker using the visibility property
- if the user has selected a date using the datepicker an **onSet** event will be dispatched
- inside the callback handler for the aforementioned onClose event, use jquery's **click()** method to simulate a click on the invisible timepicker
- just like the datepicker, the timepicker will dispatch an onSet event too. Let's use it to finally combine the values of the date and timepicker into one

```js
// DatePicker
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
  onSet: function() {
    $('.timepicker').click();
  },
  format: 'dd mmm, yyyy',
  today: '',
  clear: '',
  close: '',

});

// TimePicker
$('.timepicker').pickatime({
  onSet: function() {
    var tempString = $('.datepicker').val() + " at " + $('.timepicker').val();
    $('.datepicker').val(tempString);
  },
  clear: '',
  format: 'HH:i'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://hateable-tests.000webhostapp.com/classic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://hateable-tests.000webhostapp.com/classic.date.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://hateable-tests.000webhostapp.com/classic.time.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://hateable-tests.000webhostapp.com/picker.js"></script>
<script src="https://hateable-tests.000webhostapp.com/legacy.js"></script>
<script src="https://hateable-tests.000webhostapp.com/picker.date.js"></script>
<script src="https://hateable-tests.000webhostapp.com/picker.time.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="datepicker">
<input type="text" class="timepicker" style="visibility: hidden;">
```

As per your question in the comments, here's a way to get the individal pickers after date & time have been set:

```js
// DatePicker
var dPicker;
var initialDateSet = false;
var backup = "";

$('.datepicker').pickadate({
  onSet: function() {
    if (!initialDateSet) {
      $('.timepicker').click();
    } else {
      var tempString = dPicker.get();
      var tempString2 = backup.substr(backup.indexOf("at"), backup.length);
      $('.datepicker').val(tempString + " " + tempString2);
      backup = $('.datepicker').val();
    }

  },
  onOpen: function() {
    dPicker = this;
    if (initialDateSet) {
      var index = $('.datepicker').val().indexOf("at");
      if ($('.datepicker')[0].selectionStart > index) {
        dPicker.close(true);
        $('.timepicker').click();
      }

    }
  },
  format: 'dd mmm, yyyy',
  today: '',
  clear: '',
  close: '',
});

// TimePicker
$('.timepicker').pickatime({
  onSet: function() {
    var tempString;
    if (!initialDateSet) {
      tempString = $('.datepicker').val() + " at " + $('.timepicker').val();
      $('.datepicker').val(tempString);
      backup = tempString;
      initialDateSet = true;
    } else {
      tempString = backup.substr(0, backup.indexOf("at"));
      $('.datepicker').val(tempString + "at " + $('.timepicker').val());
      backup = $('.datepicker').val();
    }
  },
  clear: '',
  format: 'HH:i'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://hateable-tests.000webhostapp.com/classic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://hateable-tests.000webhostapp.com/classic.date.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://hateable-tests.000webhostapp.com/classic.time.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://hateable-tests.000webhostapp.com/picker.js"></script>
<script src="https://hateable-tests.000webhostapp.com/legacy.js"></script>
<script src="https://hateable-tests.000webhostapp.com/picker.date.js"></script>
<script src="https://hateable-tests.000webhostapp.com/picker.time.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="datepicker">
<input type="text" class="timepicker" style="visibility: hidden;">
```

Comment: With this, there's a glitch. Suppose I click on the input then close outside it automatically pops timepicker if datepicker closes, not knowing I have not selected date. How do I tackle this?

Comment: Yeah sorry! I've looked up some old specs that claimed datepicker has an onSelect event. Unfortunately it didn't work, so I replaced it by onClose. Now I realized it has an onSet event too. I've updated my code above!

Comment: With this, it seems like a good fix. Another quick thing, since there's no individual timepicker input field, is there a way that after the selection of date and time is completed which should look something like: "30 Apr, 2019 at 00:47" if I click on date it opens up the date picker to edit and if I click on the time it opens up the time picker to edit?

Comment: It's cumbersome but possible. I've added a second code snippet to my answer above to demonstrate it.

Comment: Whenever I click on next/previous month it pops up time so it doesn't let me go next and back. Any solution?